# Is a signal ignored before the delivery of the signal to the process or after?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals

How SIGCHLD is being ignored from system() function call.

The manual suggests that system() will block SIGCHLD. So it will be delivered when it is unblocked.

Which of the following is correct:

1. system() -> SIGCHLD Generated -> blocked -> unblocked -> SIGCHLD delivered -> ignored
2. system() -> SIGCHLD Generated -> blocked -> unblocked -> ignored -> not delivered

Comment: "*Which of the following is correct: ...*" -- Probably the first. From https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-5.html : "When a signal is blocked, it is not delivered (that is, no signal handling routine is called), but remains pending."